# jQuery hover drop down menu not working with CMS

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, content-management-system

I'm using GetSimple CMS, and currently trying to replace my old static navigation bar with drop down menus with the GetSimple version. I seem to have gotten it working, but I'm running into a problem: I can't get the jQuery script to work.

Before I included the CMS, I had a basic submenu setup:

```
<ul class = "navbar">
   <li><a>Item</a>
      <ul class="slidedown">
         <li><a>SubItem</a>
      </ul>
   </li>
  <!--Again-->
</ul>
```

I targeted `.slidedown` and gave it a `position:absolute` and `display:none` in my CSS, and ran this script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".navbar li").hover(
  function () {
     $($(this).find(".slidedown")).stop().fadeIn(200);
  }, 
  function () {
     $($(this).find(".slidedown")).stop().fadeOut(300);
  }
);

});
```

After I included the CMS, however, it changed the markup to basically the same thing, except the `.slidedown` `ul` didn't have a class (in this case, `.slidedown`). So I figured I'd just target it manually, using `.navbar li ul` in place of `.slidedown` as a selector. This worked fine in my CSS, but it broke the script. I'm assuming it's the `.find()` parts of it, because some text I told to put in every div on the hover worked. The menus also displayed correctly (although all at once) when I took away `display:none` from the CSS.

Here's the fiddle with what the CMS generated and my script/css:
http://jsfiddle.net/R3ndH/1/

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

**Also note:** I tried using my old HTML markup, not including the CMS, and just taking away the `.slidedown` class. This didn't work as well, so I assume it has nothing to do with the CMS and everything to do with the markup/selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R3ndH/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.navbar li').hover(  
   function(){  
      $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeTo('slow', 1);  
   },  
   function(){  
      $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeOut('slow', 0);  
   });  

});
```

Comment: Ah, didn't catch that. Forgot about the `this`. Works now, thanks!